# Exporting video from user's iTunes library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmediaitem, avassetexportsession

I have searched and read the docs, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this (seemingly-simple) issue I've run into.  I have songs exporting working fine from the user's iTunes library, and it downloads into the user's documents folder with no issues every time, but videos just don't seem to work.

I have it showing an MPMediaPickerController (allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES) to allow the user to select either videos or songs from their downloaded library.  When done, here is the relavent code I'm using:

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController*)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection*)mediaItemCollection {
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession;

    for (MPMediaItem *item in mediaItemCollection.items) {
        NSURL *assetUrl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
        MPMediaType type = [[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType] intValue];
        if (type >= MPMediaTypeMovie) {
            exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:[AVAsset assetWithURL:assetUrl] presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];
            exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
            filePath = [title stringByAppendingString:@".mov"];
            exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSFileManager documentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath]];
        } // .. check for song-types here and set session up appropriately

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            // never gets into AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted here for videos 
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get every time is the following:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11820 "Cannot Complete Export" UserInfo=0x1e1a2180 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try exporting again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Export}
```

Not very helpful. :(  I feel like I may be potentially missing something obvious here.  Am I going about this the correct way?  Is it potentially a problem with me trying to "force" it to MOV-format?  Or perhaps needing a different way of setting up the export session?

For reference, I'm using iOS 6.0.1 on my iPhone 5 for testing, with a baseSDK of 6.0.  Thanks in advance for any guidance that can be offered on this!

**Additional Info #1**: something that's odd. It seems to crash immediately with a "SIGTRAP" if I set the outputFileType to "AVFileTypeAppleM4V".. I wanted to try M4V, because when I do a log output of the assetURL, I see something like: ipod-library://item/item.m4v?id=12345. Don't know if that makes a difference or not, but odd that it just crashes like that if I try m4v format.  Probably because it's not in the supported filetypes list (see next info point).

**Additional Info #2**: The supported file types I get (from calling the "supportedFileTypes" method are: "com.apple.quicktime-movie" and "public.mpeg-4". The "exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset" include all of the video ones, including m4a, low/med/high quality, and the specific dimensions ones. I have tried EVERY combination of all these, such as AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie and AVFileTypeMPEG4 for fileTypes, and all of the presets, including the low/med/high, and all of the dimension ones. It never fails that I get the "Cannot Complete Export" error.

**Additional Info #3**: I am also using a Deployment Target of 5.1. But yes, I have tried 6.0, and it gives the same error. :(

**Additional Info #4**: If needed to know, the movie I'm testing with is a "Pilot" TV show, one video, the first one I saw in iTunes that was free.  So I downloaded it for use in this app.

**Additional Info #5**: Not sure if this is important, but the "hasProtectedContent" method returns YES for the AVAsset (and AVURLAsset if I convert).  May not make a difference, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think that your `AVAssetExportSession :initWithAsset:presetName:` function is supposed to be called with an `AVURLAsset` instead of an `AVAsset`.  If so, you need to replace `[AVAsset assetWithURL:assetUrl]` with `[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetUrl options:nil]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply on this.  Unfortunately I get the same "Cannot Complete Export" when I replace the AVAsset with the AVURLAsset you copied within my initWithAsset line of code. :(  I kept the preset as AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality, the "shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse" to YES, and the outputFileType set to AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie (with the filepath as .mov).  I appreciate the response on it, though.  Any other thoughts on things to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to replicate the issue and doing some testing, I strongly suspect the protected content is an issue. Here's why:

I copied your code, and tested it on my iPod Touch (5th gen, iOS 6.0.1), though instead of coming from a media picker, I just let it loop through all the videos I have on the device (7 of them.) It worked great, and called the completion handler and made proper .mov files in the documents directory of the app sandbox. I moved the .mov files to my Mac and they all played.

These video files had the hasProtectedContent as NO.

So I placed a video file I got from the iTunes store, and confirmed it had the hasProtectedContent as YES. Interestingly, when I try to get the URL from MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL, I get nil for the protected/iTunes obtained video.

I strongly suspect the media protection is the problem.

Here's the variation of code that I used. I didn't change your conversion code at all, just how the URLs are supplied:

```
// select all the video files
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeMovie] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *items = [query items];

// now go through them all to export them

NSString* title;
NSURL * url;
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession;
NSString *storePath;
AVAsset *theAsset;

// we fill put the output at this path
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];


// loop through the items and export
for (MPMediaItem* item in items)
{
    title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    NSLog(@"Title: %@, URL: %@",title,url);

    theAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];

    if ([theAsset hasProtectedContent]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is protected.",title);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ is NOT protected.",title);
    }

    exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:theAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];

    storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov",title]];

    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"done!");
    }];

}
```

Out of curiosity, are you checking the `AVAsset exportable` flag?

Comment: Spot-on. Confirmed with someone from Apple last night. I had not checked the "isExportable" flag before, but now that I put a quick check, it is returning "NO" for this asset.  Apple indicated that any media which has protected (DRM) content, i.e. can be checked via "hasProtectedContent" property, does not support operations such as playback, export, getting metadata, etc. However, video content we create ourselves should be fine.  I am a bit concerned and currently looking for a place this is documented?! Lots of time wasted.. Regardless, thank you for your answer and taking the time!